# Problems building clamcour

Tags: clamav

when i try to install clamcour from terminal, it gives me  this error, somebody can help me?

```
calmcourdir# ./configure

checking for libraries containing socket functions... -lc
checking for socket... yes
checking for bind... yes
checking for listen... yes
checking for accept... yes
checking for shutdown... yes
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_un.sun_len... no


System log functions
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking for openlog... yes
checking for syslog... yes
checking for closelog... yes


Time functions
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for strftime... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for sysconf... yes


BZip2 support
checking bzlib.h usability... no
checking bzlib.h presence... no
checking for bzlib.h... no
checking for BZ2_bzWriteOpen in -lbz2... no


GZip support
checking zlib.h usability... no
checking zlib.h presence... no
checking for zlib.h... no
checking for gzopen in -lz... no


LibClamAV support
checking for /usr/bin/clamav-config... no
checking for /usr/local/bin/courier-config... no
checking for /usr/clamav/bin/clamav-config... no
checking for /usr/local/clamav/bin/clamav-config... no
./configure: line 25234: : command not found
configure: error: Cannot find clamav-config
```

Comment: What version of clamcour are you trying to install?   The one I've seen doesn't come with a 'configure' script.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've already considered trying clamav-milter , which is in the repositories .

From `apt-cache show clamav-milter`:

```
 This package contains the ClamAV milter for use with sendmail. It can
 be configured to be run either standalone, or using clamav-daemon.
Homepage: http://www.clamav.net/
```

Otherwise, it appears you are missing some dependencies for clamcour .  (What version of `clamav` is on your system?)

Trying to build this myself, with clamcour "Current release" 1.0.0-1 - Development (beta)
from the [clamcour page](http://www.becrux.com/index.php?page=projects&name=clamcour) 
it looks like you'll need

```
 libboost1.42-all-dev courier-mta libxml2-dev libclamav-dev
```

Comment: The version is the last one from repositories, i installed it 2 weeks ago

Comment: @user10778 -- you mean the version of clamav is the lastest?  Do you also have the dev library installed, as above?